# Could I hold both an EASA license and a UK CAA license?

Tags: easa-regulations, pilot-certification, student-pilot, caa-uk-regulations

With all the ongoing mess with Brexit at the moment, I'm trying to figure out the wood from the trees so to speak. However there seems to me a bit of mass confusion with it all.

I'm just wondering if I could hold two licences at the same time? If the CAA go ahead and leave EASA, could I hold an EASA ATPL (CPL ME IR)and CAA ATPL (CPL ME IR) together?

If I can, I suspect this is in ICAO somewhere within licensing? And how would I go about it? Can I apply to on authority based on my results with the other (e.g. CAA with EASA results) or would I have to duplicate and thus spend more money to get a CAA one?

Comment: There is no regulation that says you can’t hold licenses from different authorities at the same time. Thousands of student pilots every year travel to the US, get an FAA license, then go home and get another license there.

Comment: I hold several country's pilot licenses (all ATP), although I only keep the one that I currently fly with valid, otherwise it would cost an arm and a leg, and a lot of traveling.

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! I don't know much about EASA and it's possible there is a good answer to this, however the effects of Brexit are still very unclear in many areas.

Answer (score 5):

**Yes**, you can hold both. The UK CAA is now completely separate from EASA. Comparable to EASA vs FAA.

> At this time, there are no agreements or associated Annexes in place between the EU and the UK in this area. Licensing and Training under the oversight of the UK CAA is now considered as third country licensing and training
>
> [*Irish Aviation Authority - Brexit Notice*](https://www.iaa.ie/news/2020/01/31/brexit-notice-personnel-licensing)

- From EASA to a UK application: possible.
- From UK to an EASA application: not possible. (Sadly EASA have ["shut the door"](https://www.easa.europa.eu/the-agency/faqs/brexit), it is very unfortunate)

If you hold an EASA licence you can apply to the UK to hold an equivalent UK Part-FCL licence. It involves the inevitable administration costs from both the UK CAA and the EASA state to send details. You will also require a UK CAA Class 1 medical - initial/revalidation at the discretion of the UK CAA **AME** (not the UK CAA itself).

If you are a former UK Licence holder, there are some further considerations.

> *UK CAA - Eligibility for application*
>
> Licence holders who fit the below criteria can apply for a UK PART-FCL licence > using this application route:
>
> pilots, instructors and examiners who previously held a UK issued Part-FCL/BFCL/SFCL and have not had a licence issued at a higher level since 1 January 2021
> EASA licence holders whose licence date of initial licence issue is prior to 31 December 2020
> Licence holders who fall into the below criteria cannot use this route and must instead email FCLweb@caa.co.uk (subject heading ‘Attention Tech: EU Conversion’) for further advice:
>
> pilots, instructors and examiners who previously held a licence with the UK CAA and have had an EASA licence issued at a higher level since 1 January 2021
> EASA licence holders whose licence was issued after 31 December 2020
>
> [UK CAA - Conversion of an EASA flight crew licence to a UK part equivalent licence](https://www.caa.co.uk/General-aviation/Pilot-licences/Conversion-of-an-EASA-flight-crew-licence-to-a-UK-part-equivalent-licence/)

[image]

Comment: Well, as it has turned out, UK need EU more than the other way around, so... but true, it is sad that political bravado messed up the affairs of a whole nation.

Comment: I would be careful to jump to conclusions here. The UK doesn’t really need pilots at the moment anyway as the largest carriers by PAX numbers (predominantly short haul due to COVID) already operate on European AOCs. By 2024, when there might actually be a serious global pilot shortage, I wouldn’t be surprised if an UK to EASA conversion process comes available. My integrated ATPL flight school had around 15-20% French students at any one time and probably another 10-20% of other EU nationals. The UK has an awful lot to offer still.

Comment: I was referring to the situation on a more general level, but you are correct on all accounts. I just wonder how on earth a nation allowed itself to get self-shafted in this way. It's almost like a Monty Python sketch...

Answer (score 0):

You may need to wait until the dust settles to see exactly what the regulations end up being but if the rest of the world is an indicator then yes you can hold licenses from various places at once. Licenses can in some cases be issued simply by applying and proving your currently issued one is valid (from somewhere) [as is the case with the FAA](https://www.faa.gov/licenses_certificates/airmen_certification/foreign_license_verification/) but this will likely vary by jurisdiction.